# Filling date column with current date and time?

Tags: php, pdo, insert

I have this code for adding new products to my database, but It does'nt work at all.

I want that date be inserted automaticly by code not manually, and because of that I used now() in my mysql, but now I use PDO and I have now idea, how could I do it. Here is my code:

```
<?php
require"../scripts/config.php";
if(isset($_POST['product_name'])){
  $product_name  = $_POST['product_name'];
  $product_category= $_POST['product_category'];
  $product_quality= $_POST['product_quality'];
  $product_size = $_POST['product_size'];
  $product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
  $product_description= $_POST['product_description'];

  $q = "INSERT INTO tuotteet (name, category, quality, size, price, description, date_add) 
        VALUES(:name, :category, :quality, :size, :price, :description, NOW())";
    require "../scripts/connect.php";
    $query = $connect->prepare($q);
    $result = $query->execute(array(

    ":name" => $product_name,
    ":category" => $product_category,
    ":quality" => $product_quality,
    ":size" => $product_size,
    ":price" => $product_price,
    ":description" => $product_description  
                  ));
}
?>
```

Comment: 1.`":date_add" => now()` NOT required. 2.`$categoru` != `$category`

Comment: Ask one question at time

Comment: @davidstrachan More like, _won't work_

Comment: now there is just one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `NOW()` in SQL which is good approach, but you are also trying to pass in the `:date_add` parameter which doesn't exist in the SQL as a placeholder.  Don't bind value on `:date_add` when you `execute()`.

You need to check for and handle errors around your database accesses.

And you're also missing a single quote at `if (isset($_post['product_name]))` which should have been `if (isset($_post['product_name']))`